# I cant recreate java.lang.NullPointerException Android

Tags: android

Ive got a strange issue that has me beating my head into a brick wall. In my android app I have a method that checks the mobile state and depending on the outcome pulls an image from on line. I started to receive java.lang.NullPointerException in the developer console. It was being caused by there being no mobile state to check. Simple enough and was fixed with an if statement.

This method was in several activity's and the fix was applied to all. For some reason I am still receiving errors in the console but only for one of the activity's. The error message is the same as last time, and Ive been through the code a million times it shouldn't be doing it has the same fix as the other activity's. Also I cannot re create the error, which is making it impossible to fix. As far as I can see its not broke.

Any suggestions of what to do in this situation? Would a try and catch be appropriate?

Comment: A NullPointerException is quite common, perhaps it has a different reason this time? Look at the logcat and the stacktrace, it should provide more information.

Comment: I'm not sure to correctly understand your problem : you had a problem, then now you cannot have it again ? So there is no problem... Maybe it was just a bad build, so the second launch was OK. However without your sources, we are not really able to understand what can be the problem neither told you if try/catch is  a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning (in eclipse, Project -> Clean...) your project.  I find this sometimes fixes issues with the app seamingly not being updated when changes are made to the source...whether the source being a resource or source code.

Comment: Ill certainly give this a go, Ill be releasing an update in a day or so, so Ill be able to see then if its worked

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps check if there are any contexts not clearly defined. Or if you simply wrote one of "(this)", try being more explicit: "(mainactivity.this)"